# Algorithm review for time complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

1. I would like to know whether this works in worst case as `Θ(n+m)`?

`n` is size of `i_StringForSearch`, `m` is size of `i_SubStringToFind`.

2.Is there any program which is recommended to check time complexity of a given code, I prefer a free tool which is well recognized.

Thank you

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String i_StringForSearch, String i_SubStringToFind)
    {
        int strForSearchIndex = 0;
        int subStrToFindIndex = 0;
        boolean endOfStringToSearch = false;
        boolean foundSubString = false;
        boolean isThereASequenceOfMatching = false;


        while(!endOfStringToSearch && !foundSubString)
        {
            if(strForSearchIndex == i_StringForSearch.length())
            {
                endOfStringToSearch = true;
            }

            else if(i_StringForSearch.charAt(strForSearchIndex) == i_SubStringToFind.charAt(subStrToFindIndex))
            {
                isThereASequenceOfMatching = true;
                if(subStrToFindIndex == i_SubStringToFind.length() -1 )
                {
                    foundSubString = true;
                }
                subStrToFindIndex++;
                strForSearchIndex++;
            }

            else if(i_StringForSearch.charAt(strForSearchIndex) != i_SubStringToFind.charAt(subStrToFindIndex))
            {
                if(isThereASequenceOfMatching)
                {
                    subStrToFindIndex = 0;
                    isThereASequenceOfMatching = false;
                }
                strForSearchIndex++;
            }
        }

       return foundSubString;
    }
```

Comment: I believe the algorithm is wrong. `isSubstring("aaab","aab") == false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Answering your question: yes, the algorithm is `O(n+m)`. Each
   iteration increases `strForSearchIndex`, so there are at most `n`
   iterations. [this is assuming `i_StringForSearch.length()` is done
   in `O(1)`, which is usually true].
2. The algorithm is wrong with the counter example of `isSubstring("aaab","aab") == false`.
3. You might want to have a look on [Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and/or [Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) and/or [Aho-Corasick Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)

Comment: Okay what about a free tool to calculate time complexities, do you know one?

Comment: @JavaSa: Such an algorithm does not exist. It is closely related to the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) (There is no general algorithm that can determine if another algorithm will stop or not). There are heuristics I believe, but I am not familiar with these I am afraid.